# BrowserActivity has leaked window

Tags: android, windows, memory-leaks

What's this error?

```
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248): Activity com.android.browser.BrowserActivity has leaked window android.widget.LinearLayout@44f997e0 that was originally added here
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.android.browser.BrowserActivity has leaked window android.widget.LinearLayout@44f997e0 that was originally added here
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:227)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at com.android.browser.BrowserActivity.showFakeTitleBar(BrowserActivity.java:1037)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at com.android.browser.BrowserActivity.access$2100(BrowserActivity.java:153)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at com.android.browser.BrowserActivity$7.onPageStarted(BrowserActivity.java:2597)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:234)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-25 09:38:33.233: ERROR/WindowManager(248):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you have started any window (say: Alert or Dialog) in BrowserActivity, and before dismissing that window, you have started new Activity.

Dismiss that window before starting new Activity.

Comment: Now I realized that if i open an url from web and before dissmissing the window with that page I press back then I get this error. So, I think I can't do nothing with this error,...the good part is that I don't get Force Close.

Comment: check whether window is there or not? , onBackPressed() method. if is there then dismiss it and finish your activity, or if not then just finish your activity.